# Is this an equivalent definition of $\aleph$-space?

Tags: general-topology

A k-network is a family $\mathcal{N}$ such that for all compact $C\subseteq X$ and its neighbourhood $U$ there is a finite amount of elements of $\mathcal{N}$ such that their union $N$ satisfies $C\subseteq N\subseteq U$.

For a pseudobase we require instead that there is $N\in \mathcal{N}$ such that the above holds.

An $\aleph_0$-space is a regular space with countable k-network/pseudobase.

Similarly $\aleph$-space is a regular space with $\sigma$-locally finite k-network.

Can we replace k-network with pseudobase in the definition of $\aleph$-space as well?

Comment: I'm not actually sure if we can exchange basis in the Nagata-Smirnov theorem by a basis closed under finite unions. If this is possible (or not) then it might give me some insight here as well.

Comment: A Hausdorff space with a point-countable pseudobase has a countable pseudobase (this is due to Shou Lin). Since every locally-finite collection is point-finite, any regular Hausdorff space with a $\sigma$-locally-finite pseudobase is an $\aleph_0$-space. Any non-separable metric space is a space admitting a $\sigma$-locally-finite k-network but no $\sigma$-locally-finite pseudobase.

Comment: @Tyrone that makes sense, thank you! I can find Lin's paper myself, I think this result is in one of the references I have.

Comment: @Tyrone I'm sorry for bothering you again, but do you have any accessible references for the fact that Hausdorff space with point-countable pseudobase has a countable pseudobase?

Comment: You can find Shou Lin's paper *A Study of Pseudobases* on his website. I just tracked down [a version kept on researchgate](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/268837063_A_study_of_pseudobases). As a more accessible reference, the relevant statement appears on page 29 of the book *Generalized Metric Spaces and Mappings* by Shou Lin and Ziqiu Yun.

Comment: @Tyrone Thank you, I actually couldn't find this article anywhere on the internet, so I tried other sources, finally finding the book you mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Tyrone in a comment, I was able to find a reference.

As seen in the book **Generalized metric spaces and Mappings** by *Shou Lin* and *Ziqiu Yun*, a regular space with point-countable pseudobase, which in the book is called point countable strict k-network, is a $\aleph_0$-space. This is theorem 1.6.4 in that book.

In particular it answers my question, regular spaces with $\sigma$-locally finite pseudobase are $\aleph_0$-spaces.

It also answers my side-comment, a regular space with $\sigma$-locally finite base closed under finite unions must be a first countable $\aleph_0$-space, hence a separable metric space.